# python - wx.lib.pubsub.Publisher not working when called from buttons pressed?

Tags: python, wxpython, messaging

I'm implementing a [MVC](http://wiki.wxpython.org/ModelViewController) app using [wxPyton](http://www.wxpython.org/), and I have an issue with [wx.lib.pubsub.Publisher](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.lib.pubsub.PublisherClass-class.html).

I'd like to keep my Controller as separated from my View as possible. For example, I don't want my controller to 'know' the names of the buttons used in the view. On the [wxPython example](http://wiki.wxpython.org/ModelViewController), the controller has to know them, so it can bind actions to them.

```
class Controller:
...
self.view2.add.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.AddMoney)
self.view2.remove.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.RemoveMoney)
```

I thought about 'decoupling' things a bit more, using `wx.lib.pubsub.Publisher` messages instead:

```
from wx.lib.pubsub import Publisher as pub

class Controller:
...
pub.subscribe(self.AddMoney, "MONEY ADDED")
pub.subscribe(self.RemoveMoney, "MONEY REMOVED")
```

The view would bind the controls to an action that would just send the messages.

But alas, it doesn't seem to work. Either the view refuses to send events, or the controller refuses to receive messages from the view. I'm not sure.

Here's a small sample app that illustrates my problem (I've tested it with python 2.6.6 and wxPython 2.8)

```
import wxversion
wxversion.ensureMinimal('2.8')
import wx
from wx.lib.pubsub import Publisher as pub

class View(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Main View")

        self.button = wx.Button(self, -1, "foo?")
        self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.ChangeFoo)

    def ChangeFoo(self, evt):
        print('Binding works')
        pub.sendMessage("FOO CHANGED")

class Controller:
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.view = View()

        pub.subscribe(self.FooChanged, "FOO CHANGED")

        self.view.Show()

    def FooChanged(self, message):
        print('Messaging works')


app = wx.App(False)
Controller(app)
app.MainLoop()
```

The app shows a window with a big button. The expected output after pressing it is:

```
Binding works
Messaging works
```

But instead I get:

```
Binding works
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to save a reference to your controller otherwise the object gets GC'd and therefore won't exist by the time the message is sent. Change the second-to-last line to:

```
controller = Controller(app)
```

Comment: Nice spotting! I've updated the wxPython example so no one else falls on the same trap. May all your histories be merry, and all your paths flat and straight.